# Springboot Whitelabel Error Page with JSF (AWS)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, jsf, facelets

I have an old (inherited) project that I need to deploy on AWS but I get some problems related to the template folder.

This project has an index.xhtml on "src\main\webapp" instead of "src\main\resources\templates", I think it is beacuse it uses jsf but I'm new on Springboot and jsf pages.

In the documentation I've got it says that in order to open the web you need to visit http://localhost:5000/index.jsf so to solve it I made a class with

```java
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"", "/"})
    public String index() {
        return "redirect:/index.jsf";
    }
}
```

In local works but the problem I get is that when I deploy it on AWS with Elastic Beanstalk, I create a new Java application on it to upload the jar file made with maven.

But when I enter to the application I always get this message:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Thu Jun 18 14:52:25 UTC 2020
>   There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
>
> /index.jsp

I try to:

1. Search where it's configured the custom folder but I didn't find it.
2. Move the index.xhtml file to templates but doesn't work.
3. Add to **application.properties** file **spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/** to set the default folder.
4. Instead of Java application I made a Tomcat application on Elastic Beanstalk and upload a war file made with maven but I get a tomcat 404.

The project has a page on swagger-ui to test de API Rest petitions, I don't know if it might cause some problems.

**POM.XML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>es.xxxxxxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxxxxxxxxx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>xxxxxxxxxx</name>
    <description>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>



        <!-- JSF -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8-02</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8-02</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hppc</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port = 5000
```

More Info:
I noticed that the WEB-INF folder was missing so I created it (also clasess and lib folders) and I added these files.

**web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
              version="2.2">
    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

Besides I added this line on **pom.xml**

```xml
<outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
```

But the problem continues.

Comment: _"This project has an index.xhtml on "src\main\webapp" instead of "src\main\resources\templates", "_ nope... besides the .xhtml instead of .html it is the default location in basic webapp homepages when created with maven. And your outputdirectory is wrong never out them there ( I have a dejavu btw). Your basic problems seem to stem from a misunderstanding of maven.

Comment: And your spring mvc controller should not be used with jsf. And using thimeleaf instead of facelets with jsf is very uncommon too.

Comment: Sorry, As I say I don't know a lot about maven and Springboot, I am a COBOL developer and I have had to implement this with very little knowledge. Any kind of help will be welcome.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I think this project has Spring MVC for the part of users petitions and JSF for the view, I need to investigate more and discover how to make the index.xhtml the main page.